# Getting DB Query between time stamps

Tags: sql, postgresql

Have a large DB with alarms, trying to query if an alarm was raised at any time between to times. Tried multiple things but unfortunately not working.

So that could be

- open before the times used in the query and closed after the times in the query on not closed yet
- open before and closed between the times
- open and closed between the times
- open between the times and closed after on not closed yet

Query has multiple AND's which work as expected until I query the alarms between. I only want to do this section of the query when the vars  :to_open and/or :from_open are not null

```
Select * from alarm 
WHERE 
 ((:from_open :: TIMESTAMPTZ IS NULL OR :to_open :: TIMESTAMPTZ IS NULL
          OR (
              alarm.time_created <= :to_open :: TIMESTAMPTZ AND
              (alarm.time_cleared >= :from_open :: TIMESTAMPTZ OR alarm.time_cleared IS NULL)))

           AND ((:from_open :: TIMESTAMPTZ IS NULL AND :to_open :: TIMESTAMPTZ IS NOT NULL)
                OR alarm.time_created >= :from_open :: TIMESTAMPTZ
           )
           AND ((:from_open :: TIMESTAMPTZ IS NULL AND :to_open :: TIMESTAMPTZ IS NOT NULL)
                OR
                (alarm.time_created >= :from_open :: TIMESTAMPTZ OR
                 (alarm.time_created <= :from_open AND (alarm.time_cleared >= :from_open
                                                        OR alarm.time_cleared IS NULL)))
           )
      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL's range types should be just what you need there:

```
SELECT * FROM alarm
WHERE tstzrange(time_created, time_cleared, '()')
   && tstzrange($1, $2, '()');
```

This is so simple because a NULL argument to `tstzrange` causes the interval to be unbounded on that end.

If you want an index to speed up the query, use

```
CREATE INDEX ON alarm USING gist (tstzrange(time_created, time_cleared, '()'));
```

You can also use an `spgist` index; experiment to find out which one works better for you.

Comment: Hi, haven't tried this yet but  time_ created & time_clrared are cols in the DB and from_ open and to_open are args passed into the qeery from a function call.  Will this work if I just  cast the args like from_open :: TIMESTAMPTZ

Comment: Certainly. I'll replace them with `$1` and `$2` in the answer to make clear that they are not columns.